# Interaction between lattice displacement waves with different polarization for harmonic crystals

Tags: solid-state-physics, crystals, phonons

I'm studying the classical theory of harmonic crystals and I don't understand a step in the derivation.

Let $\vec u_{s,\vec R}$ be the displacement from the equilibrium position of the basis atom $s$ (with mass $m_s$) of the cell in position $\vec R$.

It can be proven that the EOM of the displacements is:

$$
m_s \ddot{\vec{u}}_{s,\vec R} = - \sum_{s', h} G_{s s'} (\vec h) {\vec u}_{s', \vec R+\vec h}$$

Using the anstaz $\vec{u}_{s, \vec{R}} = \vec{A}_s e^{i \vec{q}\cdot\vec{R}-i\omega t}$ and taking the Fourier transform of the dynamical matrix we get to:

$$
m_s \omega^2 \vec{A}_s =\sum_{s'} G_{s s'} (\vec q) \vec{A}_{s'}
$$

In the next step of the proof the off-diagonal elements of the dynamical matrix are neglected and therefore the equation become and eigenvalue problem:

$$
m_s \omega^2 \vec{A}_s = G_{s s} (\vec q) \vec{A}_{s}
$$

I don't understand the reason behind this step: why there are not cross-interactions between waves with different polarization vector inside the crystal?